# How to get access to functions from main activity with navigation components

Tags: android, android-fragments

Before navigation component was launch, I created base activity to handle **Commom Staff** like *progress bar*, *app bar* etc...

For my understanding, in navigation component the `MainActivity` acts like **"base activity"** and can host the common components like *drawer*, *app bar* etc.

How can I get access to functions from my activity?

Or do I need also create base fragment for common fragment functions?

Main Activity(In the layout there is fragment and progress bar):

```
 class  MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG = "MainActivity"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ")
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun showProgressBar(show: Boolean) {
        if (show) progress_bar.visibility = View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
}
```

How can I get access to `showProgressBar` for example inside my fragments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
((activity) as MainActivity).showProgressBar(show)
```

or create an interface on your fragment and implement it on your MainActivity

*MyFragment*

```
class MyFragment : Fragment {

    var myInterface: MyInterface = null

    interface MyInterface {
        fun showProgressBar(show: Boolean)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        myInterface = context as MainActivity
    }

}
```

*MainActivity*

```
class  MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MyFragment.MyInterface{
    private val TAG = "MainActivity"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ")
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun showProgressBar(show: Boolean) {
        if (show) progress_bar.visibility = View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
}
```

then just call `myInterface?.showProgressBar(show)` on your fragment

Answer (score 1):

You can add Interface that contain your function
and implement this interface where you want to use